# Selecting DIVs that are rotated and overlapping

Tags: html, css

I have a table as shown in the jsFiddle below. I want the background color to change (like a highlight) when I mouse over it. I have it *mostly* working, but there are dead spots. I'm assuming this has to do with the overlapping of the box model as I'm rotating the divs 45 deg.

[jsFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/2wtrr1qo/) :: Notice how the background will light up when you mouse over the lower part of each header, or on any part of the last header. Then there's dead spots on the previous ones.

```
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="rotateHeader">
      <div>
        <span>This is my title</span>
      </div>
    </th>
    <th class="rotateHeader">
      <div>
        <span>This is my title</span>
      </div>
    </th>
    <th class="rotateHeader">
      <div>
        <span>This is my title</span>
      </div>
    </th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>100</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Anyone have any ideas how I can get the entire div of each header to highlight when mousing over it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just another `z-index` problem. You have to set it on divs, otherwhise the `hover` starts on `<th>`.

```css
* {padding: 0; margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
table { border-collapse: collapse; margin: 10px; }

.rotateHeader {
  height: 100px;
  width: 40px;
  min-width: 40px;
  max-width: 40px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  padding: 0;
}

.rotateHeader > div {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 0;
  left: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-45deg,0deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-45deg,0deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(-45deg,0deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-45deg,0deg);
  transform: skew(-45deg,0deg);
  overflow: hidden;
  border-left: 1px solid #E34949;
  border-right: 1px solid #620F0F;
  border-top: 1px solid #620F0F;
  background-color: #b71c1c;
  color: #FFF;
}

.rotateHeader span {
  -webkit-transform: skew(45deg,0deg) rotate(315deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(45deg,0deg) rotate(315deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(45deg,0deg) rotate(315deg);
  -o-transform: skew(45deg,0deg) rotate(315deg);
  transform: skew(45deg,0deg) rotate(315deg);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px; 
  left: -25px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 85px;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.rotateHeader > div:hover { background-color: #CE1F1F; cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="rotateHeader">
        <div>
          <span>This is my title</span>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th class="rotateHeader">
        <div>
          <span>This is my title</span>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th class="rotateHeader">
        <div>
          <span>This is my title</span>
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>100</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: well spotted + 1

Comment: wow; I feel a bit dumb now... ha ha. Thanks for spotting that! Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `th`s are not skewed but their children are. If you hover the mouse on top right of the first div, It work. It is the region that you `th`s are ended! To get rid this problem skew your `th`s also.

```css
* {padding: 0; margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
table { border-collapse: collapse; margin: 10px; margin-left: 50px; }

.rotateHeader {
  height: 100px;
  width: 40px;
  min-width: 40px;
  max-width: 40px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  padding: 0;
}
.rotateHeader{
  -webkit-transform: skew(-45deg,0deg);
   -moz-transform: skew(-45deg,0deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(-45deg,0deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-45deg,0deg);
  transform: skew(-45deg,0deg);
}
  .rotateHeader > div {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    
    height: 100%;
   
  overflow: hidden;
  border-left: 1px solid #E34949;
  border-right: 1px solid #620F0F;
  border-top: 1px solid #620F0F;
  background-color: #b71c1c;
    color: #FFF;
  }
  
  .rotateHeader span {
    -webkit-transform: skew(45deg,0deg) rotate(315deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(45deg,0deg) rotate(315deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(45deg,0deg) rotate(315deg);
  -o-transform: skew(45deg,0deg) rotate(315deg);
  transform: skew(45deg,0deg) rotate(315deg);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px; 
  left: -25px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 85px;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  }
  
  .rotateHeader:hover div { background-color: #CE1F1F; cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="rotateHeader">
        <div>
          <span>This is my title</span>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th class="rotateHeader">
        <div>
          <span>This is my title</span>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th class="rotateHeader">
        <div>
          <span>This is my title</span>
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>100</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```